# Visualize PMI data in viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We have models that has PMI data in it. As a feature we need to visualize PMI data in APS Viewer. I have gone through documentation but could not find anything useful.
Can you someone please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what PMI data refer to? If it is a specific file format, APS has not supported such format to translate its metadata. The supported formats are available at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

Comment: if the file you testing with is supported with the list above, but PMI data is additional data that is not extracted, please share a demo file with us to investigate. It can happen some specific properties of the object are not extracted. It is depends on how much interop is supported and how much the APS extractors. With a demo file, we can look into it